# Angular2 applications exposes API keys and other details

Tags: angular

I have created an application in angular2 on the same lines as "tour of heroes". My AppComponent invokes a REST API which requires a access key.

Now, when I run the app in the browser, it shows the API key in the developer console Network tab as shown below:

[image]

I am new to angular2 and possibly I don't know if there is a right way of doing things so that my API key is not exposed.

Comment: I guess the way to go is having a service in the middle (PHP, nodejs ...)